# Using map on a key/value hash treats it like a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I do

```
const pFile = {'a': "b", 'c': 'd'};

var bigExplanation = `
lots of text here
${Object.keys(pFile).map(key => `${key}: ${pFile[key]}`)}
more text here
`;

console.log(bigExplanation);
```

I get

```
lots of text here
a: b,c: d
more text here
```

where I was hoping for

```
lots of text here
a: b
c: d
more text here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebvo23ks/

## Question

Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a newline (`\r\n`) after each `map()` iteration.

Use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the `map()` result;

```js
const pFile = {'a': "b", 'c': 'd'};

var bigExplanation = `
lots of text here
${Object.keys(pFile).map(key => `${key}: ${pFile[key]}`).join("\r\n")}
more text here
`;

console.log(bigExplanation);
```

Result;

```
lots of text here
a: b
c: d
more text here
```

---

Edit; the source of the `,` was due your trying to 'insert' a object into a string, for example;

```js
const pFile = {'a': "b", 'c': 'd'};

var bigExplanation = Object.keys(pFile).map(key => `${key}: ${pFile[key]}`);
console.log(typeof bigExplanation);

const string = '---' + bigExplanation + '----';
console.log(string);
```

Here you can see that `(typeof bigExplanation)` is an [javascript Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), when adding to a string, the `,` appear between each entry.

Comment: That did the trick =) Why were there a `,` in my output? Where did that come from?

Answer (score 1):

You wrong relied on the assumption that the array is converted to a string using line breaks as separator. This is not true:

```js
const pFile = ["a: b", "c: d"];
console.log(pFile.toString())
```

To insert the required separator between the array elements (in this case, `\n` - line break) - you can, for example, use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const pFile = {'a': "b", 'c': 'd'};

var bigExplanation = `
lots of text here
${Object.keys(pFile).map(key => `${key}: ${pFile[key]}`) .join('\n') }
more text here
`;

console.log(bigExplanation);
```